godot 4 - character keeps jumping when holding jump button
i am creating a 2d platformer in godot 4 and i am running into issues during finetuning of my jump mechanic. when i hold the jump button the character keeps jumping. i want the character only be able to jump again when releasing the jump button and also reseting the jump buffer as the player lands on the floor.
i created a gravity component which i import in my player.gd script which handles the jumping mechanic so i can reuse it for other scripts aswell.
# gravity_component.gd
@export var actor: Node2D
@export var jump_height : float = 75.0
@export var jump_time_to_peak : float = 0.5
@export var jump_time_to_descent : float = 0.35

@onready var jump_velocity : float = ((2.0 * jump_height) / jump_time_to_peak) * -1.0
@onready var bounce_velocity : float = ((jump_height) / jump_time_to_peak) * -1.0
@onready var float_velocity : float = ((jump_height) / jump_time_to_peak) * -1.0
@onready var jump_gravity : float = ((-2.0 * jump_height) / (pow(jump_time_to_peak, 2))) * -1.0
@onready var fall_gravity : float = ((-2.0 * jump_height) / (pow(jump_time_to_descent, 2))) * -1.0

func input_jump():
    if Input.is_action_pressed("jump"):
        actor.velocity.y = getJumpVelocity()

func float_jump():
    if Input.is_action_just_released("jump") and actor.velocity.y < (getJumpVelocity() / 2):
        actor.velocity.y = getFloatingVelocity()

now i can reuse this in my player.gd main script which looks like this:
# player.gd
var jump_available = true
var jump_buffer = false

func _physics_process(delta):
    gravity_component.apply_gravity(delta)
    handle_animations()
    handle_movement(delta)
    handle_jump()


func handle_jump():
    # DONT MOVE_AND_SLIDE HERE NUB
    if is_on_floor():
        if jump_buffer:
            gravity_component.input_jump()
            jump_buffer = false
        else:
            jump_buffer = true
    elif not is_on_floor():
        gravity_component.float_jump()
        state = JUMP

func handle_animations():
    match state:
        # some other code here
        JUMP:
            animatedSprite.play("jump")
            animatedSprite.flip_h = DIRECTION == -1
        _: # default
            animatedSprite.play("idle")

things i have tried:
i tried replacing Input.is_action_pressed("jump"): with Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"): but then the character doesnt always react to the jump input even when on the ground.
i was also thinking of reseting the jump buffer once the player releases the jump button like this but i could not get it working
func resetJumpBuffer():
    if jump_buffer && Input.is_action_just_released("jump"):
        jump_buffer = true

full code can be found here:
https://gitlab.com/fiehra/dinolife

In gravity_component.gd, try replacing Input.is_action_pressed("jump"): with Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):

i did try that but then the jump doesnt always work :/ even on the floor the character will only react to the jump input after some delay (which is not consistent as far as i can tell)  i will mention it in my question tho thanks for reminding me

I believe this is the resource you need (design pattern about jump mechanism): https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html
Disclaimer, I've read this book, and found this amazing. Also, freely available.

@AustinDuling actually i removed some jump buffer code which was interfering with the is_action_just_pressed and now your suggestion is working. the jump buffer code is probably from trying to make it work in another way

@zerocukor287 thank you! that looks like a very helpful resource. Looks like i might need to refactor a bunch of my code xD i will get right to it

the setting of the jump buffer like i am doing it is not a good way to prevent jumping when holding down the jump button. instead i removed this code and started using @AustinDuling's suggestion.
# gravity_component.gd
func input_jump():
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
        actor.velocity.y = getJumpVelocity()

then i changed the player script to handle the jump differently like this:
func handle_jump():
    # DONT MOVE_AND_SLIDE HERE N00B
    if is_on_floor():
        gravity_component.input_jump()
    elif not is_on_floor():
        gravity_component.float_jump()
        state = JUMP

